Why is my apk file so big for a new app using Nativescript 8.6.5?
The apk size is 121MB, 107MB of it is in the lib folder, the libNativescript.so file is 20MB+, for x86, x86_4, arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a, this seems excessive for an application with a few components, no image files in assets, and basic dependancies.
Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "appname",
  "main": "src/main.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~16.2.0",
    "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.0",
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.6.0",
    "@nativescript/pdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-cardview": "^2.0.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "~15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@nativescript/android": "8.6.2",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "^11.2.0",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.6.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.18",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~16.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "~5.1.6"
  }
}

angular.json

{
    "version": 1,
    "cli": {
        "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
    },
    "projects": {
        "appname": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "ns"
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "appname"
}

I've removed some of the dependencies, even with that it doesn't go below 90MB.

could you share the contents of angular.json!

@NarenMurali, I have edited my question to include angular.json
